# .rvmrc syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, rvm, rvmrc

I am trying to work with a web app made by someone else. I cloned that repo and when I cd'ed into it, the .rvmrc executed. But I am getting the following error in it:

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
-bash: /home/sleepingdragon/Desktop/sharedcab/main-apps/ytaxi-apps/yTaxi/.rvmrc: line 22: syntax error in conditional expression
-bash: /home/sleepingdragon/Desktop/sharedcab/main-apps/ytaxi-apps/yTaxi/.rvmrc:'line 23: syntax error near `]]
-bash: /home/sleepingdragon/Desktop/sharedcab/main-apps/ytaxi-apps/yTaxi/.rvmrc:'line 23: `  && -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/$environment_id" ]]
```

The .rvmrc file is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This is an RVM Project .rvmrc file, used to automatically load the ruby
# development environment upon cd'ing into the directory

# First we specify our desired <ruby>[@<gemset>], the @gemset name is optional,
# Only full ruby name is supported here, for short names use:
#     echo "rvm use 1.9.3" > .rvmrc
environment_id="ruby-1.9.3-p194@ytaxi"

# Uncomment the following lines if you want to verify rvm version per project
# rvmrc_rvm_version="1.14.2 (stable)" # 1.10.1 seams as a safe start
# eval "$(echo ${rvm_version}.${rvmrc_rvm_version} | awk -F. '{print "[[ "$1*65536+$2*256+$3" -ge "$4*65536+$5*256+$6" ]]"}' )" || {
#   echo "This .rvmrc file requires at least RVM ${rvmrc_rvm_version}, aborting loading."
#   return 1
# }

# First we attempt to load the desired environment directly from the environment
# file. This is very fast and efficient compared to running through the entire
# CLI and selector. If you want feedback on which environment was used then
# insert the word 'use' after --create as this triggers verbose mode.
if [[ -d "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments"
  && -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/$environment_id" ]]
then
  \. "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/$environment_id"
  [[ -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/hooks/after_use" ]] &&
    \. "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/hooks/after_use" || true
  if [[ $- == *i* ]] # check for interactive shells
  then echo "Using: $(tput setaf 2)$GEM_HOME$(tput sgr0)" # show the user the ruby and gemset they are using in green
  else echo "Using: $GEM_HOME" # don't use colors in non-interactive shells
  fi
else
  # If the environment file has not yet been created, use the RVM CLI to select.
  rvm --create use  "$environment_id" || {
    echo "Failed to create RVM environment '${environment_id}'."
    return 1
  }
fi

# If you use bundler, this might be useful to you:
# if [[ -s Gemfile ]] && {
#   ! builtin command -v bundle >/dev/null ||
#   builtin command -v bundle | GREP_OPTIONS= \grep $rvm_path/bin/bundle >/dev/null
# }
# then
#   printf "%b" "The rubygem 'bundler' is not installed. Installing it now.\n"
#   gem install bundler
# fi
# if [[ -s Gemfile ]] && builtin command -v bundle >/dev/null
# then
#   bundle install | GREP_OPTIONS= \grep -vE '^Using|Your bundle is complete'
# fi
```

I have not worked with .rvmrc before and am a Rails noob. Could you help me find the error?

Comment: Try replacing all `$environment_id` with `${environment_id}`

Comment: User `.ruby-version` file instead of `.rvmrc`. It is safer and easier for newbie.

Comment: @codeit didn't work. Same error. :(

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier it already exists in the original repo I pulled. I don't want to mess around a lot with it. how does .ruby-version work?

Comment: Try adding ` \ ` at the end of this `if [[ -d "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments"` like `if [[ -d "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments" \ `  which will indicate the continuation of statement

Comment: @codeit: didn't work.

Comment: @mpapis So, on putting a semi colon after the ]] got the syntax error removed. But now I am getting an 'unexpected EOF' error at the least line of the file. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: @codeit So, on putting a semi colon after the ]] got the syntax error removed. But now I am getting an 'unexpected EOF' error at the least line of the file. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

Just create `.ruby-version` file containing

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194@ytaxi
```

and delete the `.rvmrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

You are using minimal version of `.rvmrc` which also is buggy, you could either fix it:

```
 if [[ -d "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments" &&
       -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/$environment_id" ]]
 then
```

and you can switch to the new `.ruby-version` file:

```
rvm get stable
rvm rvmrc to ruby-version
```

Comment: but your fix is also not working. I don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @codeit - you had to get different error, because the initial syntax problem should be fixed.

Comment: it did not get fixed. it still shows the same error. can this have anything to do with my shell? I am using /bin/bash